# TableController vs ApiController in Azure Mobile Apps

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm just getting started with Mobile Apps. I'm used to making APIs with `ApiController` of Web API.

The default project template for Mobile Apps in VS2015 comes with a sample `TodoItemController` that inherits from `TableController`. It looks like there are some CRUD operations installed out-of-the-box in `TableController` and each data object must be of type `ITableData`.

Ideally, I'd like to skip `TableController` and implement things my own way with `ApiController`.

My question is, what are the ramifications of ditching `TableController` if any? Is there any tight-coupling between App Service and the use of `TableController`?

Comment: Do you mind sharing what aspects of ITableData aren't ideal?  In the future, we may relax some of these requirements.

Comment: non-nullable guid for the Id column and non-nullable dates

Answer (score 7):

The TableController is coupled with the client SDK's table logic, and provides all the right logic & columns for the interactions needed for querying, offline sync, etc.

You can use API Controllers just fine, it mainly will depend on what features you want to use.

Comment: Can those features be implemented with ApiController?

Comment: No, if you want offline sync and client-side querying capabilities, you need to use a TableController. All other features will work fine with ApiController. Make sure you use the attribute MobileAppController, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#how-to-define-a-custom-api-controller

Comment: @lindydonna-msft what is the advantage of using MobileAppController if I only want to return json object?

Comment: @batmaci MobileAppController will set up JSON serializers in a way that is compatible with the Mobile Apps client SDKs.

Comment: Don't use it, it is a bad idea. The TableController is not worth the effort and you will eventually dump it. To add to this MS philosophy when they can't fix something, they create something new and expect you to follow.

Comment: Managing your own api sync is very easy using shiny